# sql select records between today date plus 16 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the records between today order date plus 16 hours.

`OrderDate` data type is `datetime`

i have records in database between that period but is not showing using the below query.

For example i have the below records.

```
2017-03-05 10:20:30.000

2017-03-06 10:20:30.000
```

query should return  the second record.

any suggestions to solve this issue?

**SQL Query**

```
    SELECT
  dbo.Areas.AreaName,
  dbo.Brands.BrandName,
  dbo.Orders.OrderID,
  dbo.Orders.OrderStatus,
  dbo.Customers.CustomerName,
  dbo.Customers.CustomerID,
  dbo.Customers.Phone,
  dbo.Customers.Mobile,
  dbo.Orders.OrderDate,
  dbo.Outlets.OutletName,
  dbo.Users.FirstName,
  dbo.Users.LastName,
  dbo.Sources.SourceName,
  SUM((OrderDetails.Quantity * OrderDetails.UnitPrice)) + Orders.DeliveryCharge - ((SUM((OrderDetails.Quantity * OrderDetails.UnitPrice)) + Orders.DeliveryCharge) * Orders.Discount / 100) AS Amount,
  ReceivedOrders.ReceivingDate
FROM dbo.Orders
INNER JOIN dbo.Customers
  ON dbo.Orders.CustomerID = dbo.Customers.CustomerID
INNER JOIN dbo.Outlets
  ON dbo.Orders.OutletID = dbo.Outlets.OutletID
INNER JOIN dbo.Users
  ON dbo.Orders.UserID = dbo.Users.UserID
INNER JOIN dbo.Sources
  ON dbo.Orders.SourceID = dbo.Sources.SourceID
INNER JOIN dbo.OrderDetails
  ON dbo.OrderDetails.OrderID = dbo.Orders.OrderID
INNER JOIN dbo.Brands
  ON dbo.Brands.BrandID = dbo.Outlets.BrandID
INNER JOIN dbo.Areas
  ON dbo.Areas.AreaID = dbo.Customers.AreaID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ReceivedOrders
  ON dbo.ReceivedOrders.OrderID = dbo.Orders.OrderID
WHERE  BETWEEN OrderDate AND DATEADD(HOUR, 16, OrderDate) and OrderDate=GETDATE()
GROUP BY dbo.Orders.OrderID,
         dbo.Orders.OrderStatus,
         dbo.Customers.CustomerName,
         dbo.Customers.CustomerID,
         dbo.Customers.Phone,
         dbo.Customers.Mobile,
         dbo.Orders.OrderDate,
         dbo.Outlets.OutletName,
         dbo.Users.FirstName,
         dbo.Users.LastName,
         dbo.Sources.SourceName,
         dbo.Orders.DeliveryCharge,
         Orders.Discount,
         dbo.Brands.BrandName,
         dbo.Areas.AreaName,
         ReceivedOrders.ReceivingDate
ORDER BY dbo.Orders.OrderID
```

Comment: Please show sample data.  There could be something else wrong with your query.

Comment: Keep in mind that `GETDATE()` is the current date and time. Is it your intention to only show records starting from the "current" time that the query is executed? or do you want it to include the whole day?

Comment: Records should be between order-date plus 16 hours. and order date should be equal to today date

Comment: i have tried some thing like this  BETWEEN OrderDate AND DATEADD(HOUR, 16, OrderDate) and OrderDate=GETDATE()

Comment: @Ayman You are talking of `Dates` yet you are adding `HOURS`, I'll ask my question again, where your say `order date should be equal to today date` are you taking into account the time or not?

Comment: @Stephen If he _is_ taking time into account, then his current query should already be working.  If not, then my answer should have worked (I think).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it seems neither is working for him.

Comment: yes it didn't work what i am trying to get is for example i made order on 2017-03-06 12:00:00.000 i want to show order until 2017-03-07 03:00:00.000

Comment: @Ayman try my answer

Comment: its working now thanks Stephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`GETDATE() BETWEEN Orders.OrderDate AND DATEADD(HOUR, 16, Orders.OrderDate)`

Comment: Nice guess...so it was an alias issue...I'm surprised the query ran at all given this +1

Answer (score 0):

use this to get today's date instead of just getdate() which returns present time

```
  select cast(cast(getdate() as varchar(12)) as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112)` instead of `GETDATE()` this will remove current time and convert the date to varchar with ISO format `yyyyMMdd` which doesn't need to be converted to datetime again

```
WHERE   OrderDate BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112) AND DATEADD(HOUR, 16,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112) )
```

Read more about sql date formats [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)